# Trying to get back privilege

Tags: support

I am trying to get back the privilege of asking questions. I think I am almost there due to that fact that I have had it back a few times, and then the scales tipped with another downvote or a few. But now my bad questions have all been deleted, so I can't edit them anymore. Could a mod please undelete them for me?

Comment: Well, it's a little difficult considering the nature of most of your questions that were deleted. I did restore one of them which was a duplicate that had some pretty good answers worth saving: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789190/why-not-document-write but I honestly don't know how much that helped, if at all.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, How should I proceed now? Just delete the account?

Comment: No but we could have the staff disassociate some of those other questions from your account because they are quite a way off limits. I'll speak to them.

Comment: Thanks, @BoltClock'saUnicorn!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the questions tab of your profile. At the bottom is a link called *deleted recent questions*.

There you will find your questions. You can edit them and afterwards flag them for undeletion and reopening.

Comment: The deleted questions will not appear there as they are too old.

Comment: @Oded, What should I do then?

Comment: @TJonS - Improve your **existing** not-deleted questions. I happen to agree with BoltClock'sa Unicorn - most of those questions should remain deleted.

Comment: And I agree with Oded's advice as well.

Comment: @Bolt great, now you created infinite loop of agreement! To visualize: http://i.imgur.com/5uVWRHt.png ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - dissapointed. No photoshoping of our avatars into that :(

Comment: @Oded now that's an excellent idea!